# see RAM usage in R-studio before crash?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am switching from Python to R for some projects, and I have a hard time understanding the RAM management in R - R-Studio.

I have the following two simple questions

- can we see how much RAM is being used by R at the moment? Just like in Spyder one can see that, say, 20% of the current RAM is full. That will allow me to understand if I can move one with my code, or if a memory crash is close.
- do I need to set-up a maximum amount of RAM that R can use or everything is automatic like in Python (where Spyder eats RAM as it needs it)

Many thanks!

Comment: Check `gc()` to check how much memory is being used

Comment: Check out the `pryr` package; it has a `mem_used` function that wraps `gc` and gives you a more easily interpretable number, in, say, Gb instead of bytes. Its `object_size` is a similarly convenient version of `object.size`. Generally, though, as long as you don't use more than you have, R is very good at allocating memory as as needed and returning it as possible. You shouldn't have to do anything to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `gc()` to check how much memory is being used.

And I think R uses all the memory available. However, you can also set the memory limit by    `memory.limit(size=)`.

Moreover, I would recommend using [Microsoft R Open](https://mran.microsoft.com/open/) It boosts the calculations speed as it introduces some parallel processing. Check out other Microsoft Client R and Server R as well.

Comment: would R Open speed up packages such as `dplyr` ?

Comment: I think so. I would also recommend `data.table` package for R. It is much faster to apply some dataframe functions that you do using `dplyr`. Here is a cheat sheet for datatable function https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf

Comment: MRO is primarily an optimized BLAS (Intel MKL), which just speeds up matrix operations. Some packages do use matrices under the hood, but an optimized BLAS doesn't mean your data.frame or list/object manipulations will move faster. Full parallelization is a bit more work.